# Angular $http on complete global setting

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http

I want to setup global config for `$http` response. I have to track response on all `$http` calls. I found global header setting on angular doc but i dint find how to setup global setting to get response value.

I tried using Angular Interceptors like bellow:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
    'response': function(response) {

    }
  };
   });
}]);
```

But it doesn't work. It gives `Error: response is undefined` error. How to do it?

Comment: Apparently what you are looking for is "interceptor". Look at $httpProvider.interceptors. You can intercept requrest before they are sent, and responses when received.

Comment: Thanks you @PierreEmmanuelLallemant. Actually i m new to angular so i m not sure how to do it. Can you post and example please.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http go to section "Interceptors". You have to create an interceptor factory and register it. in that factory, you can define `'response': function(response) { return response; },` which intercepts each succeeded response. There are 3 other methods if needed ;)

Comment: I just updated the question with Interceptors. Can you check what is wrong on my code please @PierreEmmanuelLallemant

Comment: you forgot to send the response back. It allows you to do pre-treatment, so don't forget to do 'return response;'.

Comment: Thank you very much @PierreEmmanuelLallemant you saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i made it working. And here is the code. Thanks to PierreEmmanuelLalemant

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider,$location) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
    'response': function(response) {
        //do whatever with response
return response;
    },
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
        if(rejection.status==404){
               //do whatever 
        }
      // do something on error

//      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },
  };
   });
}]);
```